# Gets Nodes containing the Search snippet in a document

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

Is there a way to get the node that contains the search snippet for eg:-

I have a sample xml doc

```
<pdf2xml>
  <page pageNo="1">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</page>
  <page pageNo="2">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</page>
  <page pageNo="3">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</page>
  <page pageNo="4">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</page>
</pdf2xml>
```

How do I get the pageNo for a given search result ? I tried the following

```
search:snippet(fn:doc($uri), 
  cts:query(search:parse($q, $options)),  
    <transform-results apply="snippet" xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
      <per-match-tokens>30</per-match-tokens> 
      <max-matches>1000</max-matches> 
      <max-snippet-chars>2000</max-snippet-chars>
      <preferred-matches>
        <element name="page" ns=""/>
      </preferred-matches>
    </transform-results>)
```

This does not give all the snippets as well ... what is a good a way of doing what I want to do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking for all of the snippets in a document, returning the containing element and highlighting them can be done with cts:walk and cts:snippet

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";


let $content := <pdf2xml>
  <page pageNo="1">xxxxxxxxxxxxxx 1 xxxxxxxxx</page>
  <page pageNo="2">xxxxxxxxxxxxxx 2 xxxxx foo xxxxxxxx</page>
  <page pageNo="3">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 3 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</page>
  <page pageNo="4">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 4 xxxxxxxxxxx foo xxxxxxxxxx</page>
</pdf2xml>

let $q := cts:word-query("foo")

return <results> 
{cts:walk($content, $q , 
  <result>
    <original-node>{$cts:node/parent::*}</original-node>
    <highlighted-content>{cts:highlight($cts:node/parent::*, $q, <matched>{$cts:text}</matched>)}</highlighted-content>
  </result>
  )}
</results>
```

Results in:

```
<results>
  <result>
    <original-node>
      <page pageNo="2">xxxxxxxxxxxxxx 2 xxxxx foo xxxxxxxx</page>
    </original-node>
    <highlighted-content>
      <page pageNo="2">xxxxxxxxxxxxxx 2 xxxxx <matched>foo</matched> xxxxxxxx</page>
    </highlighted-content>
  </result>
  <result>
    <original-node>
      <page pageNo="4">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 4 xxxxxxxxxxx foo xxxxxxxxxx</page>
    </original-node>
      <highlighted-content>
        <page pageNo="4">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 4 xxxxxxxxxxx <matched>foo</matched> xxxxxxxxxx</page>
      </highlighted-content>
    </result>
</results>
```

This may not be what you want, but I still offer it up as an example of some of the power you have available to you for manipulating your results (or in the example, extracting and highlighting content as a result of search or not)

Answer (score 4):

The xpath to the node that contains the match is in the path attribute of the search:match element.  When I try your example above (substituting the value "abc" in one of the pages), I get the following response from search:snippet:

```
<search:snippet xmlns:search="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
<search:match path="fn:doc("test.xml")/pdf2xml/page[1]">
<search:highlight>abc</search:highlight>
</search:match>
</search:snippet>
```

Notice the path attribute in the search:match element "fn:doc("test.xml")/pdf2xml/page[1](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/query-options#id_58295)".  That tells you which page matched.  You could access that node by passing it to xdmp:unpath().

You can get more snippets or otherwise tune the snippets following the docs: [Modifying Your Snippet Results](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/query-options#id_58295)

However, you might instead want to consider breaking out your pages into separate smaller documents, so you can determine which doc matched rather than which page within a large pdf doc.  When possible, smaller granularity docs can be simpler to manage and more efficient to search.